# Synology hybrid RAID

Tags: raid, nas, synology

I thinking about buying Synology NAS. I prefer to have, for example, two discs (1 TB), but only part of them used as mirrored (protected) storage. For example 200 GB of both discs used as 200 GB protected storage (if one disc fail, second have still my data). The other 800 GB of each disc used as merged 1600 GB unprotected storage. Synology has their own hybrid RAID, is there any option to do this?
Thanks, Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synology's DiskStation Manager does support this kind of setup. It involves going through the steps of initializing the RAID setup, with a few intricacies.

[image]

[image]

The tutorial on their [website](http://www.synology.com/support/tutorials_show.php?q_id=558&lang=enu#t4_2) walks you through the whole process.